# How to fix TypeError: jest.replaceProperty is not a function when mocking a const

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typeerror

I have a file of `const` values, and I want to mock one of those properties to change its value.

```
const constsMock = jest.mock('./consts', jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ myConst: true }));

jest.spyOn(constsMock, 'myConst');
```

I tried the above and got the following error:

> Cannot spy on the myConst property because it is not a function; undefined given instead. If you are trying to mock a property, use `jest.replaceProperty(object, 'myConst', value)` instead.

Makes sense. So I tried:

```
import * as consts from './consts'
jest.replaceProperty( consts, 'myConst', true )
```

Which resulted in:

> TypeError: jest.replaceProperty is not a function

So I tried this:

```
import { replaceProperty } from 'jest'
```

...which results in a TypeScript warning:

> Module '"jest"' has no exported member 'replaceProperty'.ts(2305)

I don't understand why because the `replaceProperty()` function is documented in the [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestreplacepropertyobject-propertykey-value).

Can someone help me use this function correctly to mock a const value?

Comment: check your jest version, the `replaceProperty` method was introduced in jest 27.0.0

Comment: @Chiril Both `jest` and `@types/jest` are at v29.5.0, the latest release. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

for anyone stumbling on that:
https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object

seems like the `replaceProperty` function is only available, when jest is explicitly imported

```
// https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object
INFO
The TypeScript examples from this page will only work as documented if you explicitly import Jest APIs:

import {expect, jest, test} from '@jest/globals';
```